# IndexPath for UITableView Not Working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm trying to determine the `indexPath` of the select row of my `UITableView` so I can pass the relevant data accordingly.  Right now it keeps logging `0` no matter what cell I select.  Any ideas why?  (Yes, the `IBOutlet` for the table is hooked up properly).

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"patientChart"])
    {
        UITabBarController *tabBar = (UITabBarController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        PatientChartViewController *vc = [tabBar.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        NSIndexPath *path = [self.appointmentTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        vc.appointmentDictionary = [self.appointmentArray objectAtIndex:path.row];
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you deselect cell after it was selected?

Comment: You're right.  I moved the deselect line to before the performSegue line and works fine now. Thanks.

Comment: If it won't be a problem to you I will post it as an answer and I'll be thankfull if u'll accept it =)

Comment: In my case it didnt work because i had a button inside a cell which triggered segue. By pushing a button, there was no call to delegate...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method `indexPathForSelectedRow` will return index of selected row if row is selected or 0 otherwise.

So, for example, if `cell` has been selected and later deselected then you won't get its `index path` by calling `[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];` because no one cell is selected at that time.

Comment: @LukeMcneice then your `tableView` is always `nil` or nothing is selected.

Answer (score 1):

If using iOS5 the solution for this is declare an instance in .h and set property to copy as shown below.

```
NSIndexPath *path;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSIndexPath *path;
```

Assign the indexpath value to the instance i.e path in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

I encountered this issue when tried to execute this on iOS5 and get it resolved as mentioned above. Hope this help u.